# When sizing image via CSS, text appears over image

Tags: css, html, image

The web page I'm working on has a right sidebar with 2 images. As the page gets narrower, the images extend beyond the sidebar. I want to decrease the image size at a breakpoint so as to look good on a tablet as well as desktop. But when I size it via CSS (instead of inline HTML) the text from the div above and below it appear over it.

```css
/* Sidebar/side column */
    
    .side {
        width: 30%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        font-family:monospace;
       }
    
     /* Sidebar/side column inner rounded corner div*/
    
       .sideinner {
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 325px;
        font-family:monospace;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background: #89aad6;
        padding: 20px; 
        margin: 20px;
        align-self:center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
       }
    
    
    /* sidebar text */
    .sidetext
     {
        font-size: .84em;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
     }
    
    /* sidebar images */
    .sideimage
     {
        align-self:center;
     }
```

```html
<div class="side">
  <div class="sideinner">
    <div class="sidetext">
      <b>Is my child's language where it should be?</b><br> It is not unusual for us to receive calls from concerned parents months or even years after it would have been advisable. At times, the parents may have been told by friends or even well intentioned
      pediatricians not to worry. We suggest that <i>you</i> are the best judge. The info-graphics below depict norms for speech and language development. And, although they are rules of thumb, they are accurate, especially as your child approaches 4,
      when teachers, friends, and even employees in a store should understand your child all of the time.
    </div>
    <div class="sideimage">
      <img src="images/speech-intelligibility.png" width="250" alt="Infographic depicting typical speech intelligibility by age. At 1 year, child should be understood by strangers 25% of the time, by 2, 50%, by 3, 75%, and by 4, 100%.">
    </div>
    <div class="sidetext">
      In earlier years, such as at 1 or 2, there is more variation, but even at those ages, if your child seems to be behind, you should give a speech-language pathologist a call to discuss. Most speech-language pathologists will be happy to talk with you.
      We certainly are. Many delays in the earlier years will not require treatment or even a formal evaluation. But every delay <i>should</i> require a conversation, as certain issues become much harder to correct at an older age.
    </div>
    <div class="sideimage">
      <img src="images/rough-guide-to-language-development.png" width="250" alt="Infographic depicting a rough guide to language development, with the following bullet points: 1. Expect first words between 12 and 18 months with a “spurt” of language development likely before 2. 2. Grammar should be correct mist of the time by 4 years of age. 3. Anticipate hearing 4 to 5 word sentences by 4 years of age. 4. “Other people” will understand almost everything your child says by the time he or she is 4.">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Text does'nt appear over the image for me with the given code example.

Comment: add `width: 100%` to the `img`?

Comment: If images extend beyond the sidebar give `max-width: 100%;` to the image so that it looks proper in every screen. and for text issue, I am agreed with @MauriceNino, text doesn't appear over the image

Comment: Sorry I was not at all clear with my question. When I posted the question I thought I was clear by the way I stated it that the code i posted with inline HTML specifying image size worked, but when I tried via css it failed. Looking back not I realize it was not at all clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    
    /* Sidebar/side column */
    
    .side {
        width: 30%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        font-family:monospace;
       }
    
     /* Sidebar/side column inner rounded corner div*/
    
       .sideinner {
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 325px;
        font-family:monospace;
        border-radius: 25px;
        background: #89aad6;
        padding: 20px; 
        margin: 20px;
        align-self:center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
       }
    
    
    /* sidebar text */
    .sidetext
     {
        font-size: .84em;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
     }
    
    /* sidebar images */
    .sideimage
     {
        align-self:center;
     }

     @media(max-width: 991px){
      .sidetext {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
      }
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="side">
  <div class="sideinner">
    <div class="sidetext">
      <b>Is my child's language where it should be?</b><br> It is not unusual for us to receive calls from concerned parents months or even years after it would have been advisable. At times, the parents may have been told by friends or even well intentioned
      pediatricians not to worry. We suggest that <i>you</i> are the best judge. The info-graphics below depict norms for speech and language development. And, although they are rules of thumb, they are accurate, especially as your child approaches 4,
      when teachers, friends, and even employees in a store should understand your child all of the time.
    </div>
    <div class="sideimage">
      <img src="https://catchthemes.com/demo/euphony-free/files/2017/03/pexels-photo15-920x1047.jpg" alt="Infographic depicting typical speech intelligibility by age. At 1 year, child should be understood by strangers 25% of the time, by 2, 50%, by 3, 75%, and by 4, 100%." style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <div class="sidetext">
      In earlier years, such as at 1 or 2, there is more variation, but even at those ages, if your child seems to be behind, you should give a speech-language pathologist a call to discuss. Most speech-language pathologists will be happy to talk with you.
      We certainly are. Many delays in the earlier years will not require treatment or even a formal evaluation. But every delay <i>should</i> require a conversation, as certain issues become much harder to correct at an older age.
    </div>
    <div class="sideimage">
      <img src="https://catchthemes.com/demo/euphony-free/files/2017/03/pexels-photo15-920x1047.jpg" alt="Infographic depicting a rough guide to language development, with the following bullet points: 1. Expect first words between 12 and 18 months with a “spurt” of language development likely before 2. 2. Grammar should be correct mist of the time by 4 years of age. 3. Anticipate hearing 4 to 5 word sentences by 4 years of age. 4. “Other people” will understand almost everything your child says by the time he or she is 4." style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much, Anshu! No more text-over-image and it resizes. Perfect! :)